# How does entanglement work for states where number of particles is undefined

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

Entanglement and separability are often described in terms of tensor products of particle states. For example the Alice/Bob two qubit example.

Many states do not possess a definite number of particles. For example, coherent state of the simple harmonic oscillator.

How does entanglement and separability apply in such cases?